# angular material default style/animation not working after custom theme

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular5

I recently have a problem with my application after I add/edit the theme.css file. Some of angular material style is not applied anymore such as position and animations and background color.

What I have done to the Theme.css file:

The original theme.css

[image]

After edit, trying to acheive different theme for different user.

[image]
[image]

After I have modified the theme, so now I can acheive that the app can change the color base on what class is defined in enviornment.ts file.

in app.component.html
[image]

however, problem come after.

1. all dialog/dropdown/datepicker/popup's background became transparent, So I define a class and force them to have a white background.
2. everything inside a dialog become abnormal, as picture shown below, all input/select has no border, and no material animation when click/active on the input field.
   [image]
3. From the picture above, you will see the button has no color style even I have define them. 
   [image]
4. however, there is no problem if the input field is not in a dialog, you can see the style and animation is still applied as the picture shown below.
   [image]

Anyone have experienced this? I have been trying to solve this problem for 4 days and still no clue about it.? I would be really thankful if someone could help me.

regard

Comment: Solved, After adding custom Theme , you have to configure the overlayCOntainer.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because after we adding custom theme class, we have to configure the Overlaycontainer.

This link will help to solve this issue.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes